# Image path is not working in react components laravel project

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, laravel-6, laravel-7

In my react and Laravel project, images are not showing in react components. My images are in public/img folder of Laravel and I am trying to access these in resources/js/components/services.js
i have tried these methods

```
 <img src="./img/front-end.png" alt="icons fron-end" />
<img src="{{asset('/img/front-end.png')}}" alt="icons fron-end" />
<img src={url('./img/front-end.png')} alt="icons fron-end" />
<img src="%PUBLIC_URL%/img/front-end.png" alt="icons fron-end" />
<img src={require('/img/front-end.png')} alt="icons fron-end" />
```

I have also tried by adding

```
 .setResourceRoot("/");
in webpack.mix.js and tried
<img src={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/img/front-end.png')} alt="icons fron-end" />
```

but not working, what should i do to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

resources and public folder are in the same folder so path from services.js to img folder should be like this

```
./../../../public/img/image.png
```

Comment: Farouk YD  i have added an image plz have a look